# LaTeX report chapter styles

Tags: latex, coding-style

How do I change chapter styles in LaTeX report class? I have found something about `\makechapterstyle`, but it doesn't seem to work on reports (or at least it doesn't work on *my* report :-) )
I'm prety sure there must be some way to change this.

I know that LaTeX is not much of programming, but i dont't know any better place to ask this.

Comment: LaTeX is programming. You will solve this by re-defining a function, or bringing in a code module (class) where someone has already done the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package [fncychap](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf) (pdf) seems to be what you're looking for. With it you should be able to format your chapters quite flexibly without the memoir class.

I've also used [this thesis layout](http://www-ra.phys.utas.edu.au/~jstevens/code_thesis_style.html). It uses psboxit and fancyhdr. You should be able to tweak it to your specific needs.

Answer (score 10):

I like to use the [memoir class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (pdf) for formatting reports written in LaTeX. [This](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf) (pdf) is a nice article with samples using it (both code samples and what they look like compiled). It covers things like size, indention, lines, colors, "everything".

For an introduction to LaTeX in general in which I think the memoir class is also mentioned is [The not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) (pdf). I also find [this site](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/AoPS_L_GuideLay.php) a nice quick reference for LaTeX layouting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after I tried to switch from report to memior, I got quite a lot of errors. So for now I'll probably keep the report, but next time I'm starting a fresh document I'll give it a try :-)

Comment: I highly recommend the memoir class as well.